# Does a promise resolve in time to be part of a conditional

Tags: javascript, promise

I need to test the result from a promise.  Will a promise resolve in time to be part of a conditional?

```
if (myPromise() > 15 && myOtherPromise()) {
    // do stuff when myPromise resolves to over 15 and myOtherPromise is true
} else {
    // do stuff when myPromise resolves to 15 or less or myOtherPromise is false
}
```

Or do I just need to suck it up and do:

```
let myP = myPromise();
let myOtherP = myOtherPromise();

promise.all([myP, myOtherP]).then(function(res) {
    if (res[0] > 15 && res[1]) {
        // do stuff when myPromise resolves to over 15 and myOtherPromise is true
    } else {
        // do stuff when myPromise resolves to 15 or less or myOtherPromise is false
    }
});
```

reposted from comment below for everyone "downvoting" the question and thinking this is a repeat.

> Well, yes and no. No, because I'm working with Jasmine, where the expect calls automagically resolves a promise when one is passed. `expect(myPromise()).toBeGreaterThan(15)`. So from the outside, it might have been conceivable that an if's conditional might resolve a promise before performing any comparisons.

Comment: You cannot know (That's the e point of asynchronous). Just "suck it up" or call a callback function

Comment: Well, yes and no.  No, because I'm working with Jasmine, where the expect calls automagically resolves a promise when one is passed. `expect(myPromise()).toBeGreaterThan(15)`.  So from the outside, it *might* have been conceivable that an if's conditional might resolve a promise before performing any comparisons.

Comment: @Machtyn `if` and the other control flow constructs have no support for promises. It would be interesting to have async versions of them, but I don't know of any proposal for that.

Comment: How in the world is this a duplicate of what it was marked of.  I don't see that AT all.  This is a specific question about accessing the resolved value of a couple promises which is not at what that other question is about.

Comment: @Machtyn Jasmine might be magic, but `if` is not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `myPromise` and `myOtherPromise` are functions that return promises which your code seems to indicate, then NO you can't do:

```
if (myPromise() > 15 && myOtherPromise()) {
```

Promises are objects.  So if `myPromise()` returns a promise, then:

```
if (myPromise())`
```

is always truthy and that `if` statement has absolutely nothing to do with the eventual resolved value of the promise.  So, that first `if` statement will NOT be checking the resolved value of either promise.

---

If you want to see the resolved value of a promoise, you HAVE to use something like `.then()` or `.all()` to get the resolved value.  There is no other way to access the resolved value.

If you want to examine both the resolved values of `myPromise()` and `myOtherPromise()`, then you must wait for both of them to resolve and you should use `Promise.all()` as in your second code example:

```
Promise.all([myPromise(), myOtherPromise()]).then(function(results) {
    if (results[0] > 15 && results[1]) {
        // got the result we wanted
    }
}).catch(function(err) {
    // error here
});
```

Comment: Yeah, I should have realized that when I did myOtherPromise(), and instead should have done myOtherPromise() == true in my "bad" example.

Comment: @Machtyn - Huhhh?   `myOtherPromise() == true` doesn't do you any good either.  A promise is an object.  You can ONLY get its value with something like `p.then()` or `Promise.all([p1, p2])`.  You can NEVER get it's value with `if (p)`.

Comment: @Machtyn - An `if` statement is just plain Javascript.  Some testing framework does not and can not change how an `if` statement works.

Comment: Right. That's why I said my "bad" example.

Comment: @Machtyn - So, does this answer your question?

Comment: Yes. I have to wait a few minutes before I can mark it.